# can we use prefetch_related with many-to-many relationship in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

hey guys let's say i have models like this

```
class CouponCode(models.Model):
    ......
class Product(models.Model):
   codes = models.ManyToManyField(CouponCode)
```

how can I use perefetch_related with reverse many to many relationships
I did this and I looked at the queries and I found i didn't make a query for the second table

```
CouponCode.objects.all().perefetch_related('product_set')
```

Comment: Prefetch makes one additional query and stores result in cache (in Python) so you will not see any JOIN in query

Comment: even in the sql statement ? @BartoszStasiak

Comment: Yes. `select_related` will JOIN tables. `Prefetch` will make a separate query.

You can rwad more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: thanks, but actially before i have used prefetch_related and i saw that it makes two queries from both tables or two select statement, but with reverse many-to-many relationship the reason that i couldn't see the second query because it actually make a join and i didn't pay attention to that